# How can one get a UDE report from Microsoft Fixit Center Pro?

Tags: windows, log-files, diagnostic

As per this video anybody is supposed to be able to upload their server's logs to the [Microsoft Fixit center Pro](https://wc.ficp.support.microsoft.com/Dashboards/Main/SelfHelpCase) and get an Automated diagnostic report called UDE.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-52-Microsoft-Fix-it-Center-Pro

I am able to successfully upload my logs there but couldn't figure out how to receive the diagnostic report. Has anyone tried it? Can you confirm if I missed anything ?